# PHP observer pattern / magic setter / proxing

Tags: php, proxy-classes, magic-methods, observer-pattern

I'm looking for a way to monitor when a variable in my class gets set.

For example if I have the following class:

```
class MyClass  {
    public $myVariable;
}
```

And somewhere in my code I do:

```
$class = new MyClass();
$class->myVariable = "value";
```

I would like to be able to "hook" into the setter of myVariable. So when I call $class->myVariable = "Value"; a filter would start that checks if the new value equals "Value" and if so, throws an Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define your attribute as private or protected, as usual.

Then use the magic method [__set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) to catch the access.

Best regards

Raffael

Comment: Forcing the use of private properties just to implemented some validation isn't correct in my opinion (especially if the private keyword is more or less overwritten). It's a working work-around but unfortunetly does not satisfy my need.

Comment: what? that's a standard-OOP-paradigm ... I don't get your point

Comment: Setting a property as private and then allowing access to it from outside the class later on.